# Android TextView and null pointer exception

Tags: android, textview

In my activity I do

```
TextView bTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView);

bTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));
```

where title is a string

but i get a null pointer exception at second line ie. **bTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));**

can anyone help???

**Activity**

```
public class NewsDetails extends ListActivity{

public static final String LOG_TAG = "Infra";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
    super.onStart();
    Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
    String id = myIntent.getStringExtra("content_id");
    String title = myIntent.getStringExtra("title");
    //Spanned newTitle = Html.fromHtml(title);
    //tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));
    TextView bTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "What is the value: " + bTitle);
    bTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    String xml = XMLfunctions.getBodyXML(id);
    String result = xml.replaceAll("<p>", "<p><div align=\"justify\">");
    String nXml = result.replaceAll("</p>", "</div></p>");
    TextView body = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    body.setText(Html.fromHtml(nXml));


    //Spanned body = Html.fromHtml(nXml);
    /*HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
    map.put("title", tv.toString());
    map.put("news", tv1.toString());
    mylist.add(map);*/

    /*ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "title", "news" }, new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);*/
}
```

**Layout -  listplaceholder.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

    <ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No data"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**text_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="16px"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="16px"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: plz add your all code and xml...

Comment: @CapDroid: i've added the code please have a look

Comment: Any luck so far? Please communicate your concerns, if any, so we could help more. Thank you.

Comment: @rekaszeru: Sorry for the delay in reply, thank you all for your help. I replaced textview with webview and now my application is running fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank  you all for your help. I have replaced textview with webview as i needed a lot of html formatting in my application and now my text appears in proper format and also my appliction is running fine.

Thanks

Comment: Its great that you managed it to work, but this isn't answer to your question. You had a NPE caused by trying to access a view which wasn't present in the layout you referenced.

Answer (score 2):

You should load the correct xml for your layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.text_view)

TextView bTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView);

bTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, that you actually have the

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView [...]
```

view in your activity's layout xml.

**Update**
In your `listplaceholder.xml` there is no such `TextView`! 
If you use the `text_view.xml` layout as your item renderer, then the code that tries to access the `TextView` should be placed inside your `ListAdapter` implementation's `getView` method!

Comment: i'll share my code can you have a look i'm not able to come out with a solution

Comment: i have posted a new question at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196256/android-slider-effect-to-move-to-new-page]. will be very greatful if you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i found two issue in your code

1)first thing is your TextView is not in listplaceholder.xml ..
  so you it will be null pointer...

2)and you need add this code before setContentView();

```
 Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
String id = myIntent.getStringExtra("content_id");
String title = myIntent.getStringExtra("title");
```

and let me know what u want in list and where you call setAdapter for list , where is your adapter...

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure R is imported from your project (and not from android.R namespace) in your import(s) section on the top

2) After the

```
TextView bTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView);
```

perform a log:

```
Log.d("debug", "bTitle: " + (bTitle != null));
```

and check out from terminal (if you're using Linux, if Windows, just run the logcat)

```
adb logcat | grep bTitle
```

This should tell you if you properly got the TextView from your layout (if it is present in the layout, like @rekaszeru mentioned).

3) Make sure the title variable is not null as well